# store and reload random number generator state

Tags: c++, random

I am running a large genetic simulation in the cloud.

The cost of the cloud resources can be drastically reduced by configuring the vm to be [preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible).

In order to recover from a preemption, I save the state of the agents of my population at the beginning of each generation, and when restarting, I load the state, and continue from the generation last completed, rather than having to evolve the population from scratch every time.

This has been working well, but now, for test purposes, I want to have repeatable simulations.

I seed my random number generator (currently using `std::mt19937`) with a known seed value, and this works until such time as my vm is preempted.

When I reload the current generation, I need to reload the random number generator's state at the same time, so that it too "picks up where it left off".

I have found that I can just run the generator through a tight loop, discarding all the values it would have generated until I get to the iteration I want to resume from:

```
const std::size_t generation = load_state_from_file();

std::mt19937 engine;
engine.seed(constant_seed_value);

// discard the first N generated values
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < generation; ++i)
    engine();
```

Running the random number generator through a tight loop feels a bit ugly, and potentially slow if the number of generations is very high, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: The RNGs in the standard library has [operator<< and operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator_ltltgtgt) for serializing and deserializing it's internal state.

Comment: @super brilliant, thank you! if you want to make an answer with this I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RNGs in the standard library has built-in support for serializing and deserializing through [operator<< and operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator_ltltgtgt).

```
std::mt19937 engine;
engine.seed(constant_seed_value);

// use the engine and then later

output_stream << engine; // save it's internal state to a stream
```

Then next time we use it we load the data back in

```
std::mt19937 engine;
input_stream_with_the_stored_state >> engine;
```